# Using vDSP (Accelerate Framework) with respect to audio synthesis

Tags: ios, accelerate-framework

Are there any iOS/OSx examples for which a synthesizer is using vDSP routines in the code? Or at least, some examples of manipulating/optimizing audio data. 
Would like to get aquainted with these vDSP routines to optimize code, but have not seen any such examples.

Edit: I found this: http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/a-guide-to-speeding-up-your-of-app-with-accelerate-osx-ios/10560 are there any more examples? Books with examples would be great as well.

Particularly looking at examples related to audio.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PK Mital has a bunch of nice small audio processing examples on [his Github](https://github.com/pkmital).

Comment: I think this should be more of a comment...not an answer. It wouldn't be useful without the link.

Comment: Honestly I was on the fence between comment and answer.  But, I am answering the question, not commenting on it.

Comment: with a link-only answer...it's very helpful, but probably more suitable for a comment. Thanks for the link anyway, it's a good resource.